# Register/Login System in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any tutorial or guide online that teaches you how to implement a simple user register/login system in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 4):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch (2011)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised (2012 - requires paid subscription)

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2 (2012)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this

- [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)
- [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)